# ipad-how to open a popup view controller in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

These are the files I am working on:

1. ChecklistViewController.h
2. ChecklistViewController.m
3. ChecklistTableViewCell.h
4. ChecklistTableViewCell.m
5. ChecklistTableViewCell.xib
6. DetailViewController.h
7. DetailViewController.m
8. DetailViewController.xib

I have a **ChecklistViewController** which displays a UITableView. Because I needed a different layout for the UITableViewCell, I have subclass UITableViewCell. I have created a nib file **ChecklistTableViewCell.xib** which has a UITableViewCell that contains a *label*, *button* and *switch* view. i have linked the UITableViewCell to a custom class **ChecklistTableViewCell**.

I have linked up the necessary outlets from the nib file to **ChecklistTableViewCell** class, and in **ChecklistViewController** **cellForRowAtIndexPath** I'm able to display label text.

In the UITableViewCell class file **ChecklistTableViewCell**, I have also linked and implemented a IBAction method that will be called when the button is clicked. When this method is called, how do I open **DetailViewController** as a popup?

Here is the snippet of my IBAction method:

```
-(IBAction)showPopup:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"popup");
    DetailViewController *vp = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    vp.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    vp.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    vp.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 540, 620);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "popup"? If you mean you want it to slide up from the bottom, then just use presentViewController:animated:completion: to present vp. There's no need to set the frame, a form sheet has a specific size.

Comment: i'm looking to create a popup like this. http://i.stack.imgur.com/iAlDJ.png

Comment: You can do that by adding the one line I mentioned.

Comment: could you elaborate what you mean by using presentViewController? i'm certainly not able to do it [self presentViewController:vp animated:YES completion:nil] because the showPopup method is in ChecklistTableViewCell.m and not in ChecklistViewController.m

Comment: The method should be in the view controller. You either need to add the target and action to the button in cellForRowAtIndexPath (so you can set the target to self), or you need to create a delegate protocol in your cell class, and have the controller set itself as the delegate. Then, you can call the delegate method inside the button's action method.

Comment: hi rdelmar, tks for pointing out the different ways to solving my problem. cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rdelmar is spot on with his comment. Because `presentViewController:animated:completion` is a method in the view controller, your `ChecklistTableViewCell` needs to make the view controller aware of the button click.

You have 2 choices:

Assuming your data source is your view controller, in your view controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ChecklistTableViewCell *cell = ...;

    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row; // or whatever appropriate

    [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

- (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)button
{
    DetailViewController *vc = ...; // get your "popup" accordingly using button.tag
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Or you can declare a protocol that your view controller adheres to:

```
// ChecklistTableViewCell.m
@protocol ChecklistTableViewCellDelegate
- (void)buttonTapped:(ChecklistTableViewCell *)sender;
@end

@implementation ChecklistTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    ...

    - (IBAction)showPopup:(id)sender // maybe change the name to something more appropriate
    {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonTapped:)])
        {
            [self.delegate buttonTapped:self];
        }
    }

    ...
}

// ChecklistViewController.m
@implementation ChecklistViewController : ChecklistTableViewCellDelegate
{
    ...

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        ChecklistTableViewCell *cell = ...;

        cell.tag = indexPath.row; // or whatever appropriate

        cell.delegate = self;

        ...

        return cell;
    }

    - (void)buttonTapped:(ChecklistTableViewCell *)sender
    {
        DetailViewController *vc = ...; // get your "popup" accordingly using sender.tag
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: hi allen, tks for the sample code. i'm still quite new to delegate so your code helps alot. i have decided to go with solution 1 because its much cleaner as i want to keep all the event in the controller.

Comment: @nuttynibbles no probs - I hand typed all the code in so hopefully there are no typos :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a detail view controller as pop up in iPad there is a control called UIPopoverController.

How to use UIPopoverController?

In .h file

```
    UIPopoverController *popoverController;
```

In .m file

```
     DetailviewController * objViewController = [[DetailviewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailviewController" bundle:nil];
     obj.delegate = (id )self; // if DetailViecontroller has any delegate.

     popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:objViewController];

     popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 400.0);

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:theRow inSection:1]];
     CGRect rect=CGRectMake(cell.bounds.origin.x+600, cell.bounds.origin.y+10, 50, 30); 

    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect  inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: The use of `UIPopoverController` in a `UITableView` should be avoided. It's a really jarring user experience